# Jump matching bracket in Eclipse in a text file

Tags: eclipse, search, text, brackets

I use a File named .rc which is nothing than a text document.

Windows -> Keys -> Go to Matching Bracket

I don't know which of the When reasons i have to use.

An "everywhere" would be also okay.

p.s Editing Text does not work as reason.

Comment: What is the question here.Please explain in short what you want to do and the problem you are facing.

Comment: The basic text editor does not support any of the advanced functions like bracket matching. You must use an editor which is designed for the type of file.

Comment: I want to use a shortcut to jump to the matching bracket. Of course i use a texteditor by now. But i want to do it in Eclipse.